# Soundcloud Embedded player is not working correctly on IE 10

Tags: soundcloud, internet-explorer-10

I was just testing the new IE10 that was announced today for Windows 7, and I noticed the Soundcloud embedded players don't look right.

Using this page as a sample

http://soundcloud.com/pages/widgets

The top par part of the image is IE9, where the bottom half is IE10 (10.0.9200.16438)

[image: Example of IE 10 VS IE 9]

Comment: IE10 is a *preview* and secondly this can better be answered by Soundcloud support.

Comment: Ah, true but it's released on the Win8 Surface RT. I don't have a device, but maybe it's worth a pass?

Comment: Hey, thanks for spotting this! We'll verify that IE10 gets the proper version of HTML5 widget.

Comment: This still isn't working in IE10. It does work correctly, but it is blocked until you select "Allow insecure content".